# Error : (no Creators, like default construct, exist): cannot deserialize from Object value when I deserialize string to Object

Tags: jackson, lombok, rest-assured

I am learning restAssured and trying to use Jackson and lombok annotation. I have created the following class for request and response model

```java
@Data
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
public class CreateUser {
        private String job;
        private String id;
        private String name;

        @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'")
        private Timestamp createdAt;
```

And in the below method, im trying to make a POST call using the object createUser as request body and deserialize the response string to an object and return.

```java
    public static CreateUser createUser(String name, String job) throws IOException {
        CreateUser createUser = CreateUser.builder()
                .name(name)
                .job(job)
                .build();

        String jsonResponse =  given()
                .when()
                .baseUri(baseUri)
                .contentType(ContentType.JSON)
                .body(createUser)
                .post("/users")
                .body()
                .asString();

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

        return mapper.readValue(jsonResponse, CreateUser.class);
    }
```

Im getting the below exception

```json
Cannot construct instance of `test.model.CreateUser` (no Creators, like default construct, exist): cannot deserialize from Object value (no delegate- or property-based Creator)
 at [Source: (String)"{"job":"leader","id":"398","name":"morpheus","createdAt":"2023-07-10T18:04:35.486Z"}"; line: 1, column: 2]
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of `test.model.CreateUser` (no Creators, like default construct, exist): cannot deserialize from Object value (no delegate- or property-based Creator)
 at [Source: (String)"{"job":"leader","id":"398","name":"morpheus","createdAt":"2023-07-10T18:04:35.486Z"}"; line: 1, column: 2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException.from(InvalidDefinitionException.java:67)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.reportBadDefinition(DeserializationContext.java:1452)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleMissingInstantiator(DeserializationContext.java:1028)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.deserializeFromObjectUsingNonDefault(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1297)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserializeFromObject(BeanDeserializer.java:326)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:159)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4014)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3005)
```

Comment: The error is telling you that you need a creator, such as a default (aka no-arg) constructor. You don't have one of those, because you have `@AllArgsConstructor`. You need to create a no-arg constructor, or some other Jackson-recognized creator (Jackson's docs explain those).

Answer (score 1):

Error `Cannot construct instance of 'test.model.CreateUser' (no Creators, like default construct, exist)` means you need no-args constructor.

Just add lombok annotation `@NoArgsConstructor` to class will fix your issue.